# Magento server error during password-reset

Tags: magento, passwords, reset-password, server-error

I have a Magento webshop (1.9.2.3.) with a lot of registered customers. When going to My Account -> Forgot password, a registered customer can fill out his/her e-mail address. When clicking on 'Send' button, the shop shows an 'Server Error 500'.

It's the only place where the error shows up. What can be the problem? What to do to fix this?

This is the page and you can give it try with my e-mail: pvanremmen@prsocial.nl
https://www.hoesjesonline.nl/customer/account/forgotpassword/

I hope there's a solution.

PS: The problem was there with Magento 1.9.2.2, just upgraded to 1.9.2.3 and it's still there.

UPDATE:
Error from log:
[Mon Jan 25 15:14:00.768731 2016] [:error] [pid 10335] [client 77.172.241.31:62120] PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /home/hoesjeson/domains/hoesjesonline.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 1548, referer: https://www.hoesjesonline.nl/customer/account/forgotpassword/
[Mon Jan 25 15:14:34.977753 2016] [:error] [pid 9480] [client 77.172.241.31:62129] PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /home/hoesjeson/domains/hoesjesonline.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 1548, referer: https://www.hoesjesonline.nl/customer/account/forgotpassword/

Comment: You should check the logs. 

You can find them in /var/log within your root folder of your magento installation.

Check exception.log and system.log and post it here.

Comment: And check your Apache error log for more information about why it's failing.

Comment: @Peter In the past you upgraded to Magento 1.9.2.2 or it was a clean installation?

Comment: No, it was an upgrade. Not a clean installation.
@Ahmed.hoban I disabled the logs, so I'm gonna activate it and retry

Comment: @Ahmed.hoban: See my first post UPDATE with error log

Comment: Thanks. It seems getBackend is called on a non existent EAV attribute. This requires a deeper look into the code unfortunately.

Comment: What is the best way to work here? Can I output some code you need to see? Or is it database problem? Maybe there is a way to check which attribute is missing and we can recreate it?

Comment: You need to hire someone because this seems to be a very individual problem, where access to your code is required. Posting code will not be very efficient, because the process involves multiple files.

Comment: Allright, thanks for all your replies! I'll find a developer and if possible post the answer here.

Answer (score 5):

Since Magento 1.9.2.2 it is required to send a form key with the forgot password form.

In your template *customer/form/forgotpassword.phtml* put:

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

Just under the `<form action="...">` tag.
Refresh the cache and see if the hidden input with a form key is present in the page.

Hopefully this will solve your issue :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers. The formkey was missing in the forgotpassword.phtml, but it didn't resolve the error. Any other ideas to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Open **customer/form/forgotpassword.phtml** from your theme.
Please first check form action. it should be **baseurl+customer/account/forgotpasswordpost/**

```
<form action="baseurl+/customer/account/forgotpasswordpost/">
```

Now check if form key is exist or not. If form key not exist then put below line between form tag.

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

Dont forget to flush cache.
Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the solution by a developer. The customer tables in the database were somehow corrupt after an upgrade of Magento version. Rebuilding the customer tables in the database did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this fix, go to your theme's **layout/customer.xml** and add:

```
<customer_account_changeforgotten translate="label">
    <label>Reset a Password</label>
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
            <title>Reset a Password</title>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
        </action>
        <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
            <title>Reset a Password</title>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="customer/account_changeforgotten" name="changeForgottenPassword" template="customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</customer_account_changeforgotten>
```

More details: http://www.dudesquare.nl/blog/2015/11/03/reset-password-blank-page-magento-1-9-2-2/